# Expression for a polynomial

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials

Let $s\in\Bbb R[x_1,\dots,x_n]/(x_1^2-x_1,x_2^2-x_2,\dots,x_n^2-x_n)$ and supposing for every $A\subseteq \{1,2,\dots,n\}=[n]$ we fix $\alpha_A\in\Bbb R$ and $$s\equiv\alpha_A\mod (x_u,x_v-1)_{\forall u\in A,v\in \bar{A}}$$ where $\bar{A}=[n]\backslash A$, then what is $\beta_A$ in $$s=\sum_{A\subseteq[n]}\beta_A\prod_{w\in A}x_w$$ in terms of $\alpha_A$ obtained by combinatorial inversion via mobius functions?

I just want to know how the last step in the answer to this question [Polynomials close to idempotents in quotient ring of $\Bbb R[x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1018005/polynomials-close-to-idempotents-in-quotient-ring-of-bbb-rx-1-x-2-dots-x-n#1018005) works. Here instead of $\varepsilon_A\in\{0,1\}$ we have $\alpha_A\in\Bbb R$.